# Which HTML5 tag to use for emphasizing and discussing a word?

Tags: html, tags, semantic-markup

When I want to emphasize or discuss a word that is **related to computer code** inside a block of normal text, I use the `<code>` tag.  For example:

> If you set the variable `foo` to the value `'bar'`, then something will happen.  If you set `foo` to any other value, then nothing that's any good will happen.

What is the best semantic HTML5 tag to use to emphasize or discuss a word that is **not** related to computer code?  The way I am thinking of this, it would be (or could be) styled like `<code>` but **not monospace**.  For example:

> The word ***math*** is a shortened version of the word ***mathematics***, which has its root in some ancient language that I am not going to research right now.

Comment: I would use the <strong> tag.

Comment: I don't really want to make the text **bold**, though.  I believe the semantic meaning I want is closer to `<var>`, but still not quite right.

Comment: <b> makes the text bold, but <strong> is semantic important in SEO. http://velizaratellalyan.com/seo/the-importance-of-bold-and-strong-tags-in-seo/

Comment: "[The `strong` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/strong) indicates that its contents have strong importance, seriousness, or urgency."  This is not the semantic meaning I want.  It would be closer to "This tag indicates that its content is being referenced / used as an object for discussion".

Comment: maybe use <dfn>? I don't really use this tag actually. Read more on MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element#Inline_text_semantics

Comment: Also, the linked article **does not** say that `strong` is important for SEO.  It says "There’s no an official confirmation that Google use these tags as ranking factors."

Comment: "maybe use <dfn>" - that's pretty good!  Can you post that comment as an answer, please?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for the tag indicates that its content is being referenced / used as an object for discussion

you can use `<dfn>` tag. [According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element#Inline_text_semantics):

> The HTML Definition element (<dfn>) is used to indicate the term being defined within the context of a definition phrase or sentence.

Comment: I think this is a decent fit for what I want to do. I had not seen this organized list of tags before, either. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just found the updated meaning of the `<i>` tag for HTML5.  [From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/i):

> The **HTML `<i>` element** represents a range of text that is set off from the normal text for some reason. Some examples include technical terms, foreign language phrases, or fictional character thoughts. It is typically displayed in italic type:
>
> > *Musa* is one of two or three genera in the family *Musaceae*; it includes bananas and plantains.
>
> It is a good idea to use the `class` attribute to identify why the element is being used, so that if the presentation needs to change at a later date, it can be done selectively with style sheets.

So, this is what I am going to do for this case... `<i class="example">` or similar.